# Never getting sensed from Fused sensor. Why?

Tags: android, android-sensors

I have creating a simple sensor application in Android Studio as follows.

```
package com.sensors.sensed;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mRotationSensor;
    private float[] mRotation = new float[3];

    private TextView tv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv = findViewById(R.id.tv);
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mRotationSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GEOMAGNETIC_ROTATION_VECTOR);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mRotationSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        mRotation[0] = event.values[0];
        mRotation[1] = event.values[1];
        mRotation[2] = event.values[2];
        updateUI();
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        tv.setText("Rotation: (" + mRotation[0] + ", " + mRotation[1] + ", " + mRotation[2] + ")");
    }
}
```

However, the function `void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)` is never getting called neither in *AVD emulator* nor using *Bluestacks*.

What could be wrong in my sample application? My *AVD emulator* shows all the sensors setup with certain values in the *Extended Controls* dialog box.

Also on Logcat with *AVD emulator*, I see the following two errors:

a) E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
b) E/SensorManager: sensor or listener is null

```
02-27 08:55:51.013 4834-4834/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
>>>>02-27 08:55:51.034 4834-4839/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
02-27 08:55:51.034 4834-4839/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
02-27 08:55:51.056 4834-4834/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.sensors.sensed-1/lib/x86
02-27 08:55:51.064 4834-4834/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
>>>02-27 08:55:51.095 4834-4834/? E/SensorManager: sensor or listener is null
02-27 08:55:51.101 4834-4848/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

                                                 [ 02-27 08:55:51.103  4834: 4834 D/         ]
                                                 HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xab64cc80, tid 4834


                                                 [ 02-27 08:55:51.129  4834: 4848 D/         ]
                                                 HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xacf54dc0, tid 4848
02-27 08:55:51.130 4834-4848/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-27 08:55:51.130 4834-4848/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
02-27 08:55:51.133 4834-4848/? D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xab5632a0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
02-27 08:55:51.148 4834-4848/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xab5632a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xab551d20)
02-27 08:55:51.170 4834-4848/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xab5632a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xab551d20)
```

Interestingly, I was getting a different error for a slightly modified code but same functionality when I was using *Bluestacks*:

```
E/Sensor-AccelerometerUI(xxxxx): java.io.IOException: Connection refused
```

**UPDATE**

I find that only fused sensors are not working, basic sensors like `TYPE_ACCELEROMETER`, `TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD`, etc. are although working.
What could be the reason?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have this sample code that works absolutely fine for Accelerometer but the only problem is that it's in Kotlin -

```
class AccelerometerActivity : AppCompatActivity(), SensorEventListener {

var context: Context = this
lateinit var sensorManager: SensorManager
lateinit var sensorAccelerometer: Sensor

lateinit var textView_X: EditText
lateinit var textView_Y: EditText
lateinit var textView_Z: EditText
lateinit var textView_Sensor: EditText

companion object {
    var x: Float = 0.0f
    var y: Float = 0.0f
    var z: Float = 0.0f
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_accelerometer)
    initViews()
}

private fun initViews() {
    sensorManager = getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
    sensorAccelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_MEDIUM)

    textView_X = findViewById(R.id.textview_X) as EditText
    textView_Y = findViewById(R.id.textview_Y) as EditText
    textView_Z = findViewById(R.id.textview_Z) as EditText
    textView_Sensor = findViewById(R.id.textview_status) as EditText
}

override fun onAccuracyChanged(sensor: Sensor?, accuracy: Int) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Accuracy Changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}

override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent?) {

    x = event!!.values[0]
    y = event.values[1]
    z = event.values[2]

    textView_X.setText(x.toString());
    textView_Y.setText(y.toString());
    textView_Z.setText(z.toString());

    if (x < -6 && x > -11) {
        textView_Sensor.setText("OVER RIGHT SIDE EDGE")
    } else if (x > 6 && x < 11) {
        textView_Sensor.setText("OVER LEFT SIDE EDGE")
    } else if (y > 6 && y < 11) {
        textView_Sensor.setText("VERTICAL STRAIGHT")
    } else if (y < -6 && y > -11) {
        textView_Sensor.setText("UPSIDE DOWN")
    } else if (z > 8) {
        textView_Sensor.setText("LYING STEADY - SCREEN UP")
    } else if (z < -8) {
        textView_Sensor.setText("LYING STEADY - SCREEN DOWN")
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it'll help